# When sharing a SkyDrive folder, where does it show up in the recipient's SkyDrive home page?

Tags: file-sharing, office-365

I created a SkyDrive folder and then gave 5 of my work colleagues access to read/write/upload/delete files from that folder. So far so good.

But when my colleagues go to their own SkyDrive home pages, the shared folder is nowhere to be found. When they click on "documents shared with me" the list is blank.

They can get to the folder when they click on the link I sent them, but how can they browse to the folder from their SkyDrive page?

Answer (score 1):

Looking for this also, apparently it's under development or still being considered as an option to be build later since October 2010.

- Be sure to make your 'suggestion' here by marking that you have the problem too: [microsoft answers](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windowslive/forum/skydrive-files/how-can-i-share-a-skydrive-folder-and-files-inside/0af4841d-c8ae-43a9-b39f-c0bbf9bd708d?tm=1336486485878)
- Add a feedback suggestion here: http://feedback.live.com/ that describes your issue.

I think this is the best way to get microsoft to work on this problem.